# livewire/update? not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have been at this problem for hours now... I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a modal `Volt` component

```
<?php
use Livewire\Volt\Component;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;

new class extends Component {
            public $name = '';

            public $user;

            #[On('edit-name')]
            public function edit_name($name)
            {
                        $this->name = $name;
                        $this->user = Auth::user();
                        $this->dispatch('open-modal', 'name-form-modal');
            }

            #[On('create-name')]
            public function create_name()
            {
                        $this->name = '';
                        $this->user = null;
                        $this->dispatch('open-modal', 'name-form-modal');
            }

            ...
            
};

?>

<x-modal name="name-form-modal" :show="false">
            <h1>{{ $name ? 'Update' : 'Create' }} Name</h1>

            <form wire:submit="...">

            </form>
</x-modal>
```

In the parent component

```
            <button type="button" @click="$dispatch('create-name')">Create</button>
            <button type="button" @click="$dispatch('edit-name', { name: 'My name' })">Edit</button>
@teleport('body')
            <livewire:name-form-modal  key="nf-modal" wire:key="nf-modal" />
@endteleport
```

**The problem is: When I click the `Edit` button the modal opens up just fine. After closing, then clicking again gives the error `livewire/update?... : ... not found`**

Comment: livewireScripts and livewireStyles are there in your layout?

Comment: scripts and styles are in the layout file. I have a full page component inside there is the parent component which has nested the modal. So the structure is `page->parent->modal`